# force constant value using position of a vector

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a vector with some positions

```
position = [2;5;10;12;18];
```

I would like to create a vector that looks like that

```
output = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0];
```

It means I take the difference between each value of position and in 'output' I put the number 1 for the first difference number and after 0 for the second difference number and so on..

```
diff = [3;5;2;6];
```

So, in `output` I have 3 ones, then 5 zeros, then 2 ones, then 6 zeros...

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
result = mod(sum(bsxfun(@lt, position(1):position(end)-1, position), 1) + 1, 2);
```

I'll let you figure out how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `repelem`

```
a = diff(position);
b = mod(1:length(a),2);
repelem(b,a(:)')
```

Comment: Thank you! @obchardon but I get that, and I don't know how to figure it out.. Replication factors must be a row vector of
integers or integer scalars.

Error in repelem (line 25)
 res{i} =
 flatten_(repmat(1:size(m,i),[siz(i) 1]),i);

Comment: I have not matlab open, but probably that the diff output is a column vector, so i edited my answer, it should work now

Comment: vector = vector(:)' is a little trick to ensure that vector is a row vector